# browser throw error of export/import keyword even webpack and babel is installed

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babel-loader

I am developing  a very basic and simple app with core javascript and html 
I have installed webpack v 4 and start server using

`npm run webpack`

the project compiled successfully; below is the output

```
> canvas@1.0.0 webpack /opt/parixan/canvas
> webpack-dev-server --inline --hot

ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Hash: 99985e9b8632c783a375
Version: webpack 4.12.1
Time: 819ms
Built at: 2018-06-30 18:45:48
        Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    bundle.js  354 KiB    main  [emitted]  main
bundle.js.map  406 KiB    main  [emitted]  main
Entrypoint main = bundle.js bundle.js.map
[./js/color.js] 359 bytes {main} [built]
[./js/index.js] 628 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/loglevel/lib/loglevel.js] 7.68 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/sockjs-client/dist/sockjs.js] 176 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/url/url.js] 22.8 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http://localhost:8080] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 7.75 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/overlay.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js 3.58 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/socket.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 1.05 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js] (webpack)-dev-server/node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js 161 bytes {main} [built]
[0] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./js/index.js 52 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack/hot sync ^\.\/log$] (webpack)/hot sync nonrecursive ^\.\/log$ 170 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack/hot/dev-server.js] (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js 1.6 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack/hot/emitter.js] (webpack)/hot/emitter.js 77 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack/hot/log-apply-result.js] (webpack)/hot/log-apply-result.js 1.27 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack/hot/log.js] (webpack)/hot/log.js 1010 bytes {main} [built]
    + 14 hidden modules
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

but when I navigate to the *localhost:8080/alphabet.html*  it throws an error in the console

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export .   alphabet.js:30

I also notice there is no *bundle.js* file under *build* folder as mentioned in *webpack.config.js*

here is my folder strucure

```
├── README.md
├── alphabet.css
├── alphabet.html
├── build
├── fruits
├── js
      ├── alphabet.js
      ├── color.js
      └── index.js
├── .babelrc
├── package.json
└── webpack.config.js
```

- node -v **8.9.2**
- npm -v **5.5.1**
- macOS -v **10.13.3**
- babel --version
  **6.26.0 (babel-core 6.26.3)**

#### .babelrc

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

#### package.json

```
 "scripts": {
    "webpack": "webpack-dev-server --inline --hot",
    "start": "http-server"
  },
  "main": "./js.index.js",

  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0-beta.4",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "jsxobj": "^1.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.12.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7"
  }
```

### webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: "./js/index.js",
  mode: "development",
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/build",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: "source-map",
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".html", ".js", ".json", ".css"]
  }
};
```

### /js/index.js

```
import { fetchImage } from "./alphabet.js";
import { color } from "./color.js";


const colorBox = color;
console.log("colorBox", colorBox);

const len = Object.keys(colorBox).length;

fetchImage(colorBox);
```

### js/alphabet.js

```
export const fetchImage = letter => {
  const fruit = fruits[letter] || "tamarindo";
  const request = new Request(`./fruits/${fruit}.png`, myInit);
  fetch(request)
    .then(response => response.blob())
    .then(blob => {
      const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      const img = new Image(200);
      img.src = objectURL;
      let element = document.getElementById("figure");
      while (element.firstChild) {
        element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
      }
      element.appendChild(img);
    });
};
```

My main doubt on this **alphabet.html** file

### alphabet.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Alphabet</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="./alphabet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content" >
    <section class="alphabet"></section>
    <figure id="figure"></figure>
</div>
<script  src="./js/alphabet.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I change `<script src="./js/index.js">` than it throw error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

i.e. *import* and *export* keyword not being recognized

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried using `<script type="module" ... />`? If the goal is to use `import` and `export` statements that should work.

Comment: wow.. this works like magic. please add this as answer

Comment: 1: webpack-dev-server builds bundles directly to memory, that is why it is considered better to have html-webpack-plugin, so the bundles are inserted automagically into you html.
2: You are getting this error because you are referencing an es6 file, not the actual bundle. This might not work in all browsers.

Comment: Thank you @MatheusSilva for this information but how and what to write for html-webpack-plugin

Comment: https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin
You just need template option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to enable using `import` and `export` statements, you should use the `module` type on your script tag:

```
<script type="module" ... />
```

This will be ignored by older browsers that don't support it, meaning you can make sure that older browsers don't even try to parse this. To make sure newer browsers don't parse old code, you can use `nomodule`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" nomodule ... />
```

See the documentation on MDN for more info on using the `<script>` tag like in this way: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Answer (score -1):

1: webpack-dev-server builds bundles directly to memory, that is why it is considered better to have html-webpack-plugin, so the bundles are inserted automagically into you html.

2: You are getting this error because you are referencing an es6 file, not the actual bundle. This might not work in all browsers.

---

To use `html-webpack-plugin`just add this to you build. Ps: this expects you to have a basic html, which are going to have the assets inserted to.

https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin

```
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'path/to/my/index.html'
    })
  ]
```

Comment: this gives this error while start webpack: `Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
     1 asset
    Entrypoint undefined = index.html
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./index.html] 649 bytes {0} [built]
    [./node_modules/lodash/lodash.js] 527 KiB {0} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 489 bytes {0} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/module.js] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 497 bytes {0} [built]
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.`

Comment: If you are using __dirname everywhere, you dont need context... nor .html to be in the resolved extensions. Downvoting answer because it was broke by others dont even make sense too.